# Power Bi, compare a text column by month

Tags: powerbi

I need a little help

```
+---------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
|              Name               | Opening Balance | Close Balance |    Date    |
+---------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
| LEAL MANZANO ABUNDIO            |     394,732.87  |   406,866.31  | 31/08/2018 |
| LOPEZ GRANADOS CLAUDIA CAT      |     382,567.83  |   382,567.83  | 31/08/2018 |
| ABARCA RODRIGUEZ ERNESTO        |     394,142.32  |   394,142.32  | 31/08/2018 |
| OSOLLO JUAREZ PALOMA            |     396,030.58  |   396,030.58  | 31/08/2018 |
| MACHUCA HERNANDEZ GUILLERM      |     410,809.87  |   422,943.31  | 31/08/2018 |
| LEAL MANZANO ABUNDIO            |      406,866.31 |    409,466.22 | 30/09/2018 |
| LOPEZ GRANADOS CLAUDIA CATALINA |      382,567.83 |    382,567.83 | 30/09/2018 |
| ABARCA RODRIGUEZ ERNESTO        |      394,142.32 |    394,142.32 | 30/09/2018 |
| OSOLLO JUAREZ PALOMA            |      396,030.58 |    396,030.58 | 30/09/2018 |
| MACHUCA HERNANDEZ GUILLERMO     |      422,943.31 |             0 | 30/09/2018 |
| MACIAS SANCHEZ JOSE             |      425,457.57 |    425,457.57 | 30/09/2018 |
| PARDINEZ BUCIO EDUARDO          |      434,591.25 |    434,591.25 | 30/09/2018 |
| LEAL MANZANO ABUNDIO            |      409,466.22 |             0 | 31/10/2018 |
| LOPEZ GRANADOS CLAUDIA CATALINA |      382,567.83 |    382,567.83 | 31/10/2018 |
| ABARCA RODRIGUEZ ERNESTO        |      394,142.32 |    394,142.32 | 31/10/2018 |
| OSOLLO JUAREZ PALOMA            |      396,030.58 |    396,030.58 | 31/10/2018 |
| MACHUCA HERNANDEZ GUILLERMO     |               0 |             0 | 31/10/2018 |
+---------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
```

So i have this table with clients Names and dates, i need to compare how it changed month by month, to know how many ins and outs i had.
Thank you.

Comment: Samuel,  please provide your table in your main post and not just a screenshot.  Also understand that the Spanish column headers make the data set very difficult to understand.  I was able to figure out 'debtor' but I have no idea what S.I. is versus S.F.  -- I expect it relates to "Ins and Outs" but how?  What is "it" that you need to compare?  How do you want the result to look?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Ok, now you have the table in the post, ok so as you can see i have the name of my clients and also the dates, so some clients have been added the current month but others are gone, so i need two compare the Clients from the current month with past month to know how many new clients i have and how many are gone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power BI Rolling Total Previous Month DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787125/power-bi-rolling-total-previous-month-dax)

Comment: The question that you link have calculations with integers, here i have to compare Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samuel,  I loaded your table into PowerBI and created the following visuals

[image]

This is accomplished by adding a new calculated column "Client Change."  This basically adds a column that just puts in a field that identifies a new balance when opening is 0 and closing is > 0.  Conversely, it sets the field to 'close balance' when thee opening balance > 0 and the closing = 0.   I plunk it into a matrix and use the month grain from the native date hierarchy against the names.  Some data fixing on the names is needed for truncated strings in your data set.

```
ClientChange =
    if(AND([ Opening Balance ] = 0, [ Close Balance ] > 0 )
    , "NewBalance"
    , if(AND ([ Opening Balance ] > 0, [ Close Balance ] = 0)
        , "Balance Closed"
        , " -- "
    )
)
```

I also added a measure 'client count' that counts all the rows where closing balance isn't 0.

```
ClientCount = COUNTX(FILTER(testData,[ Close Balance ] <> 0), testData[Name])
```

Hope it helps.  Please note that there is an oddity with 'MACIAS SANCHEZ JOSE' -- he has a record in September but not in August or October.  His neither his open nor close balance is 0.  It doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot Ryan, that could work, JOSE isnt there because he probably change his account to another product, thats why. Thanks again