# PowerBI Previous Month Running Total for Filtered Categories

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

The questions relates to DAX/PowerBI.
I've been trying to calculate a total for previous month for columns that contain only specific criteria (project name). My table looks more or less like this and is named Project Costs:

| Project Name | Date | Cost in Month | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 01/01/2021 | 2.000,00 | 1 | 2021 |
| Y | 01/01/2021 | 1.500,00 | 1 | 2021 |
| Z | 01/01/2021 | 4.800,00 | 1 | 2021 |
| X | 01/02/2021 | 3.000,00 | 2 | 2021 |
| Y | 01/02/2021 | 3.500,00 | 2 | 2021 |
| Z | 01/02/2021 | 2.200,00 | 2 | 2021 |
| X | 01/03/2021 | 1.000,00 | 3 | 2021 |
| Y | 01/03/2021 | 6.000,00 | 3 | 2021 |
| Z | 01/03/2021 | 2.000,00 | 3 | 2021 |

I have a slicer in my report that allows me to select from all my projects.
I want to be able to visualize different financial data relating only to the project currently selected with the slicer. I managed set up calculations for cost to date, labour to date etc., however, I am struggling to find a way to calculate a rolling previous month cost relating only to the selected project, that would be susceptible to the slicer in the visuals.

I've tried the following:

```
    Prev Month Cost Rolling = 
SUMX(RELATEDTABLE('Project Costs'), 'Project Costs'[Cost in Month],
DATEADD('Project Costs'[Date], -1, MONTH))
```

And it does not work as it says the max. argument count for SUMX is 2.
I have tried solutions suggested here too, but they don't work either (I might be doing th wrong): [Power BI Rolling Total Previous Month DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787125/power-bi-rolling-total-previous-month-dax)

Expected result:
Once the report is filtered to a project Z, in March I would expect to see in card visuals:

1. Cost to date: 9.000,00
2. Cost in previous month: 2,200.

When filtered for X in March it would want it to be as follows:

1. Cost to date: 6.000,00
2. Cost in previous month: 3.000,00

I want to calculate the entire previous month, not month to date.

I would appreciate any advise on how to tackle it!
Thanks,
J

Comment: Have you tried `PREVIOUSMONTH`? Do you want to calculate previous month to date or entire month? Also, SUMX seems too much, you could just use `SUM('Project costs'[Cost in Month])`. Please show expected result based on your data.

Comment: Hi @W.B. Yes, I tried PREVIOUSMONTH in different combinations, but stil cannot get the result I want keep on getting errors. I assume I am not using it correctly. The Expected result is in the edit of the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these measures:

`Total Project Cost = CALCULATE([Cost], FILTER(ALL(Projects[Date]), Projects[Date] <= MAX(Projects[Date])))` - this shows all historical costs up to the selected date.

`Cost = SUM(Projects[Cost in Month])` - can be used for costs in current month, for instance

`Cost previous month = CALCULATE([Cost], PREVIOUSMONTH('Projects'[Date]))`

[image]

Comment: How are you selecting dates?

Comment: I did not select any date. I would like to use a time intelligence formula that would return data for the previous calendar month. The only selection that I want to do manually is for the project name with a slicer. I am sorry if I confuse things.

Comment: You could write a formula to do that, but there is a simpler way - apply relative date filter and set it to current month.

Comment: Will try, thank you! And also sorry for late response.